# Python Django: urls.py questions

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Need a little help with my urls.py and other stuff.

How can I replicate this in Django?

1) When user requests a non-existent page it will redirect to one up the directory level. Ex: `example.com/somegoodpage/somebadpage` should be redirected to `example.com/somegoodpage`.

2) When user requests page `example.com/foo/bar/?name=John` it will make url to `example.com/foo/bar/name=John`

3) When user requests page `example.com/foo/bar/John` it will change url to `example.com/foo/bar/name=John`.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Also choose one between number 1 and 4, they conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1), if you don't want to do a separate route for every single route on your website, you'll need middleware that implements `process_exception` and outputs an `HttpResponseRedirect`.

For 2 and 3, those are rules that are presumably limited to specific routes, so you can do them without middleware.

2 might be doable in `urls.py` with a `RedirectView`, but since the relevant bit is a query string argument, I would probably make that an actual view function that looks at the query string.  Putting a `?` character in a url regex seems strange because it will interfere with any other use of query strings on that endpoint, among other reasons.

For 3, that's a straightforward `RedirectView` and you can do it entirely in `urls.py`.

Answer (score 0):

according to [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/) for number 1: 
django URL dispatcher runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL, so add a pattern that matches "somebadpage"s and assign it to a view which redirects the user to "somegoodpage".

for number 2:
the doc says "The URLconf searches against the requested URL, as a normal Python string. 
This does not include GET or POST parameters, or the domain name."
so i don't think that you can get the "?name=John" in url dispather, so if you describe what you want to do maybe I can help better
and for 3:
to capture bits of the URL and pass them as positional arguments to a view you should use  named regular-expression groups, for example :

```
url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/$', 'news.views.month_archive'),
```

and the request to /articles/2005/03/ would call the function `news.views.month_archive(request, year='2005', month='03')`, instead of `news.views.month_archive(request, '2005', '03')`.
hope this helped :)